# How to convert .txt file with no delimiter into Excel

Tags: excel, vba, vbscript

I got multiple of data in .txt file that not separated by any delimiter. It just a line of string. So far I made it this far, but I'm stuck now. Where should I continue after this? Below is sample on what I've made so far. Can someone please clarify what I should do next?

```
Dim objFSO
Dim TextFile
Dim TextRead
Dim Line, Line1, Line2, Line3
Dim Count

Const ForReading = 1 'Constant declared so that can be used throughout the script

'Name of the text file that need to be convert
TextFile = "C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Desktop\2_12_2015\HRILOANDIC20170601.txt"

'Create File system object
set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

'set the text file to read and open it in read-only mode
set TextRead = objFSO.OpenTextFile(TextFile,ForReading)

Do Until TextRead.AtEndOfStream
    Line = TextRead.ReadLine

    If Left(Line, 1) = "H" Then
        HeaderRecordType = Mid(Line, 1, 1)
        HeaderSequenceNo = Mid(Line, 2, 9)
        HeaderContractNo = Mid(Line, 11, 19)
        HeaderCreationBy = Mid(Line, 30, 1)
        HeaderTransactionDate = Mid(Line, 31, 8)
        HeaderTotalRecord = Mid(Line, 39, 9)
        HeaderTotalAmount = Mid(Line, 48, 17)
        HeaderSource = Mid(Line, 65, 2)
        HeaderFiller = Mid(Line, 67, 334)

    ElseIf Left(Line, 1) = "D" Then
        DetailRecordType = Mid(Line, 1, 1)
        DetailSequenceNo = Mid(Line, 2, 9)
        DetailContractNo = Mid(Line, 11, 19)
        DetailPaymentType = Mid(Line, 30, 10)
        DetailSettlementType = Mid(Line, 40, 1)
        DetailEffectiveDate = Mid(Line, 41, 8)
        DetailCreditAccountNo = Mid(Line, 49, 19)
        DetailCreditAccountType = Mid(Line, 68, 1)
        DetailCrTransactionAmount = Mid(Line, 69, 17)
        DetailLoanType = Mid(Line, 86, 10)
        DetailBankEmployeeID = Mid(Line, 96, 40)
        DetailIDNumber = Mid(Line, 136, 40)
        DetailIDTypeCode = Mid(Line, 176, 3)
        DetailBankEmployeeName = Mid(Line, 179, 200)
        DetailHRISProcessStatus = Mid(Line, 379, 1)
        DetailCIFnumber = Mid(Line, 380, 19)
        DetailAccountBranch = Mid(Line, 399, 5)

    ElseIf Left(Line, 1) = "T" Then
        TrailerRecordType = Mid(Line, 1, 1)
        TrailerSequenceNo = Mid(Line, 2, 9)
        TrailerTotalRecord = Mid(Line, 30, 9)
        TrailerTotalAmount = Mid(Line, 39, 17)
        TrailerFiller = Mid(Line, 56, 345)
    Else
        'Error Handling
    End If

Loop


ExcelFilePath = "C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Desktop\2_12_2015\Output.xlsx"

'Open the spreadsheet using the excel application object
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
'ExcelObject.WorkBooks.Open ExcelObject

Set SheetObject = ExcelObject.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1)

'Modify data in a cell (in this case we are adding data to c2)
'First value in the brackets = Column number
'2nd value = Cell number
SheetObject.Cells(3, 2).Value = "Test"

'Save and quit
ExcelObject.ActiveWorkbook.Save
ExcelObject.ActiveWorkbook.Close
ExcelObject.Application.Quit

objExcel.Visible = True
objExcel.Workbooks.Add

intRow = 2

objExcel.Cells(1, 1).Value="?" 'Name of a column
```

Comment: a few suggestions - 1) assign the same place in the string file to one variable `i.e. -  (RecordType = Mid(Line, 1, 1)` 2) create your excel object and set the sheet above the Do Loop 3) After you setting all the variables inside the Do Loop, write them to the Excel columns.

Comment: Are you just looking for how you should write them to the spreadsheet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Open the worksheet.
2. Loop the data writing it to the worksheet instead of storing it like you were.
3. Save and close

Something like this.

```
Dim objFSO
Dim TextFile
Dim TextRead
Dim Line, Line1, Line2, Line3
Dim Count

Const ForReading = 1 'Constant declared so that can be used throughout the script

'Name of the text file that need to be convert
TextFile = "C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Desktop\2_12_2015\HRILOANDIC20170601.txt"

'Create File system object
set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

'set the text file to read and open it in read-only mode
set TextRead = objFSO.OpenTextFile(TextFile,ForReading)

'Open the spreadsheet using the excel application object
ExcelFilePath = "C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Desktop\2_12_2015\Output.xlsx"
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set SheetObject = ExcelObject.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1)

'Change from storing the data in the below variables to writing them to the worksheet.

'Create yourself a counter for the worksheet row.
Dim lRow as long
lRow = 1

Do Until TextRead.AtEndOfStream
    Line = TextRead.ReadLine

    If Left(Line, 1) = "H" Then
        SheetObject.Range("A" & lRow).Value = Mid(Line, 1, 1)
        SheetObject.Range("B" & lRow).Value = Mid(Line, 2, 9)
        SheetObject.Range("C" & lRow).Value = Mid(Line, 11, 19)
        SheetObject.Range("D" & lRow).Value = Mid(Line, 30, 1)
        SheetObject.Range("E" & lRow).Value = Mid(Line, 31, 8)
        SheetObject.Range("F" & lRow).Value = Mid(Line, 39, 9)
        SheetObject.Range("G" & lRow).Value = Mid(Line, 48, 17)
        SheetObject.Range("H" & lRow).Value = Mid(Line, 65, 2)
        SheetObject.Range("I" & lRow).Value = Mid(Line, 67, 334)

    ElseIf Left(Line, 1) = "D" Then
        SheetObject.Range("A" & lRow).Value = Mid(Line, 1, 1)
        SheetObject.Range("B" & lRow).Value = Mid(Line, 2, 9)
        SheetObject.Range("C" & lRow).Value = Mid(Line, 11, 19)
        SheetObject.Range("D" & lRow).Value = Mid(Line, 30, 10)
        SheetObject.Range("E" & lRow).Value = Mid(Line, 40, 1)
        SheetObject.Range("F" & lRow).Value = Mid(Line, 41, 8)
        SheetObject.Range("G" & lRow).Value = Mid(Line, 49, 19)
        SheetObject.Range("H" & lRow).Value = Mid(Line, 68, 1)
        SheetObject.Range("I" & lRow).Value = Mid(Line, 69, 17)
        SheetObject.Range("J" & lRow).Value = Mid(Line, 86, 10)
        SheetObject.Range("K" & lRow).Value = Mid(Line, 96, 40)
        SheetObject.Range("L" & lRow).Value = Mid(Line, 136, 40)
        SheetObject.Range("M" & lRow).Value  = Mid(Line, 176, 3)
        SheetObject.Range("N" & lRow).Value = Mid(Line, 179, 200)
        SheetObject.Range("O" & lRow).Value  = Mid(Line, 379, 1)
        SheetObject.Range("P" & lRow).Value  = Mid(Line, 380, 19)
        SheetObject.Range("Q" & lRow).Value = Mid(Line, 399, 5)

    ElseIf Left(Line, 1) = "T" Then
        SheetObject.Range("A" & lRow).Value = Mid(Line, 1, 1)
        SheetObject.Range("B" & lRow).Value = Mid(Line, 2, 9)
        SheetObject.Range("C" & lRow).Value  = Mid(Line, 30, 9)
        SheetObject.Range("D" & lRow).Value  = Mid(Line, 39, 17)
        SheetObject.Range("E" & lRow).Value = Mid(Line, 56, 345)
    Else
        'Error Handling
    End If

    '  ************************ Don't overlook that i added this! **********
    'Increment the counter
    lRow = lRow + 1

Loop

'Then save and quit.

'Save and quit
ExcelObject.ActiveWorkbook.Save
ExcelObject.ActiveWorkbook.Close
ExcelObject.Application.Quit
```

Comment: I did do some changes base on ur codes..I forgot to put title in every IF statement.every If suppose to have their own title..SO i created this..but something when wrong..

Answer (score 1):

I have modified your code to write directly to the Excel workbook. I did not finish it completely, but gave you enough to modify the rest on your own. I also made comments as to where you had some syntax and general understanding errors. Make any column and row assignment adjustments as need be.

```
Dim objFSO
Dim TextFile
Dim TextRead
Dim Line, Line1, Line2, Line3
Dim Count

'Open the spreadsheet using the excel application object
ExcelFilePath = "C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Desktop\2_12_2015\Output.xlsx"

Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set objWB = objExcel.Workbooks.Open(ExcelFilePath) ' have to open workbook 
Set SheetObject = objWB.Worksheets(1) 'worksheets are a member of workbooks, not the Excel Application

'open the text file
Const ForReading = 1 'Constant declared so that can be used throughout the script

'Name of the text file that need to be convert
TextFile = "C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Desktop\2_12_2015\HRILOANDIC20170601.txt"

'Create File system object
set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

'set the text file to read and open it in read-only mode
set TextRead = objFSO.OpenTextFile(TextFile,ForReading)

i = 1 'to set row number for Excel paste

Do Until TextRead.AtEndOfStream

    Line = TextRead.ReadLine

    If Left(Line, 1) = "H" Then
        SheetObject.Cells(i, 1).Value = Mid(Line, 1, 1) 'HeaderRecordType to column A
        SheetObject.Cells(i, 2).Value = Mid(Line, 2, 9) 'ValueHeaderSequenceNo to column b
        SheetObject.Cells(i, 3).Value = Mid(Line, 11, 19) 'HeaderContractNo to column C

        '... keep going with your code

    Else
        'Error Handling
    End If

    i = i + 1 'to move down the Excel row to paste for each line in the text file
Loop

'Save and quit
objWB.Save
objWB.Close
objExcel.Quit
```